# Filtering tags by name only lets you view them by popularity

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, sorting, tag-search

When I am on the "Tags" tab on stackoverflow, and I sort them by "Name" (sub tab), and then I "Type to find tags",  the results I get are good, but they are ordered by popularity when I want them to be in alphabetical order so I can find the right one more efficiently.

Shouldn't I be able to see them in Name order when I filter them?

Here is an example of where the results were a little murky to wade through. Go to tabs, name and find "script"  -- there are about 45 tags with script and they are all over the place in terms of order.

Comment: If you associate your accounts you'll get 100 rep.  Go to your profile and hit the accounts tab.

Comment: @Lance: Looks like he did already, but he doesn't have enough rep to get the bonus.

Comment: @Lance: That only applies to users with at least 200 rep on one of the two sites being associated.

Comment: @mmyers, ok thanks, didn't realize that he didn't have 200 on SO.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the Tab search box defaults in both the `popular` and `name` tabs to sorting by popularity then name.

I think you're right that in the `name` tab, it should sort by name first.

Answer (score 1):

OK, we now subsort by the tab you're on. Funny, it's been this way for almost 1 1/2 years and nobody noticed, I guess.

Comment: this change seems to have gotten reverted.  The same situation occurs on both the Tags and Users pages.