# Tags cannot be sorted by alphabetical order

Tags: bug, tags, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Filtering tags by name only lets you view them by popularity.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42701/filtering-tags-by-name-only-lets-you-view-them-by-popularity)

Today I was searching for some tags under Super User's "Tag" tab, and I realized that the tags cannot be sorted by alphabetical order when I clicked on the "name" tab next to the "popular" tab. For example, I'm writing "Server" in the tag search box, it brings the results in tag count order, then I click on "name" tab, and the search results are gone. Then I type "Server" again, but the results are in popularity order although "name" tab is active.

I wondered if the same thing happens on Stack Overflow and Server Fault, and the result was the same after several trials.

I tried these on both IE8 and Firefox 3.6.6.

Comment: Known issue. Searching for original bug report...

Comment: Gosh, I know I've seen a report for this before, but I can't find it right now. :(

Comment: @Jon It's the same thing with User search, perhaps you might be thinking of that?

Comment: The dupe is where it starts and ends up way back with it being the same as searching on the Users page. @jon

Comment: @random: This question is not a duplicate of 9666. He mentioned the state retention, but then went on to mention something else which is the main topic in the title.

Comment: I agree with Jon. Besides, 9666 is marked as status-completed, but the bug is still present.

Comment: I'm not saying this question isn't a dupe (I'm 99% sure it is), but it's not a dupe of 9666. I've voted to reopen in the meantime. That one *is* completed though -- one of the proposed solutions was to clear the text box when returning to the page, which is the behaviour I see when I try it now. (Pretty weak solution if you ask me, but nevertheless completed.)

Comment: YES! FINALLY! Here is the dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42701/filtering-tags-by-name-only-lets-you-view-them-by-popularity -- as predicted, it wasn't tagged properly.